# how to make a form field be required with hook form alter

Tags: 8, forms

I want to alter a form to make the revision log be required.
with drupal 8, I am adding this in a module

```
$form['revision_information']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

but the field does not become required.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is this structure accurate?

Comment: I think it is , if I do a print_r I can see it.

Comment: I believe there was a similar question this month and if there is an attached widget, it also needs to be set as required.... can you post the form item in the question.

Comment: hi Kevin, is what I put in the question what you wanted?

Comment: It looks like this is just a `details` type, not an input

Comment: hi Kevin I reposted the object that i see now

Comment: What you posted isn't what you are trying to access. One says revision information, the other says revision log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this was the answer:

```
$form ['revision_log']['widget'][0]['value']['#required']=TRUE;
```

thanks for the tip about the widget Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old case but wanted to share (for those new comers) my experience on how I managed to nail the issue in D7 for the above case.

Sol: $form['FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;

Note: Remember to replace the "FIELD_NAME" part with your referring field.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to make a field required on form alter what you need is

```
$form['FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

In your case it didn't work because it's not the nested field and it's a group

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2177469

```
$form ['revision_log']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

**if you want to make the email field required, the following snippet works**

```
$form['account']['mail']['#required'] = TRUE;
```